# If an algorithm of O(lg(n)) with n=100 takes 1s to run, how can one compute how long n=1000 would take?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am currently reading "The Pragmatic Programmer" by Andrew Hunt & David Thomas. I came across this passage:

"For example, suppose you’ve got a routine that takes 1s to process 100 records.How long will it take to process 1,000? If your code is O(1), then, it will still take 1s. If it’s O(lgn), then you’ll probably be waiting about 3s. O(n) will show a linear increase to 10s, while an O(nlgn) will take some 33s. If you’re unlucky enough to have an O(n^2) routine, then sit back for 100s while it does its stuff. And if you’re using an exponential algorithm O(2^n), you might want to make a cup of coffee—your routine should finish in about 10^(263) years."

Can someone show me the math of how he came up with the times for the O(lgn), O(nlgn), O(n^2), and O(2^n) cases? I understand O(1) is real time, so n=anything would be the same 1s. The linear O(n) case also makes sense, because n=1000 records is simply 10x n=100 records, which means the runtime would be 1s*10=10s.

Comment: generally speaking measuring algorithms with small n is kinda meaningless. You could have micro-optimizations in the implementation that can stronger effect. let's say 100 is big enough, though.

Comment: Also, big-O-notation drops constants, which can be VERY IMPORTANT when trying to convert to time.  For O(n) Algorithms: t=.999+n/1000 is 1s with 100 entries, but a mere 1.01s with 1000 entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I agree with the *actual* figures posted but the concept is solid. What you need to do is figure out how the *workload* changes based on the input value.

---

Take the `O(lg N)` example (where `lg` is the notation for `log10`), and we'll assume a constant multiplier `c` to get the times (this assumption is most likely the case why my figures will differ from the book).

So, `(c * lg 100)` gives you 1 second and, since `(lg 100 = 2)`, that means `(c = 1/2)`. Applying that to the input size of 1000, `(1/2 * lg 1000)` gives you 1.5 seconds.

---

For `O(NlgN)`, `(c * 100 * lg 100)` gives you 1 second and, since `(100 lg 100 = 200)`, that means `(c = 1/200)`. Applying that to the input size of 1000, `(1/200 1000 lg 1000)` gives you 15 seconds.

---

For `O(N2)`, `(c * 1002)` gives you 1 second and, since `(1002 = 10,000)`, that means `(c = 1/10,000)`. Applying that to the input size of 1000, `1/10,000 * 10002` gives you 100 seconds.

---

And finally, the `O(2N)` case.

Since `(c * 2100)` gives you 1 second, that means `(c = 1/2100)`. Applying that to the input size of 1000, `(1/2100 * 21000)` gives you (I'll break this out since the numbers are getting bigger):

```
  (1/(2^100)) * 2^1000
= 2^1000 / 2^100
= 2^900
= 8.4 * 10^270 seconds
= 2.6 * 10^263 years (using 86,400 secs/day, 365 days/year).
```

---

And *that's* where the truly enormous figure comes from. In short:

```
Complexity     Duration     From book
----------     --------     ---------
O(1)                1 s           1 s
O(lgN)            1.5 s           3 s
O(N)               10 s          10 s
O(NlgN)            15 s          33 s
O(N^2)            100 s         100 s
O(2^N)         10^263 y      10^263 y
```

Not *exactly* the same figures as found in your book but well in line with the orders of magnitude, which is probably the best you can hope for when doing complexity analysis.

Comment: usually ln is denoted as natural log and lg, could be arbitrary.  For binary search the base is 2

Comment: That makes sense. I understand all of the lg ones now. But, the O(2^n) is still confusing me.... 10^263 years?!

Comment: @Danny Rogers Yes O(c^n) is horrible as an algorithm. The same property is used in cryptography, so you cannot break a cypher without the key before head death of the universe